# Weird artifact in blender render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image]

I'm trying to recreate a spa water bottle, to get some Blender practice. An example of the bottle:
[image]

Around the bottle are some round carvings. I created these with a Difference Boolean with a torus. I've hidden these torusses (tori?) from the view and renderer.

However, when rendering (with Cycles Render), I see some weird shape, like one of the torusses isn't really hidden. When looking with the rendered viewport shading in 3D view, I don't see the extra torus (which is what I expect).

What could this be?

Modifiers applied to the bottle, in order: subsurf, 8 booleans, solidify.

The rendered view (with unwanted artifact):
[image]

The viewport view:
[image]

EDIT:
I've doublechecked all modifier visibilities and the visibilities of the torusses themselves, and I don't see anything odd. See the image below.

Additional info, I made the torusses by extruding a circle over a circular beziercurve, and creating a mesh from that.

EDIT2:
I've added the Blend file to the top of this question

[image: The visibility of all objects and modifiers]

Comment: Restricting viewport visibility (hiding) and restricting render visibility are different things. In the Outliner, uncheck the camera icon to hide your torus in the final render?

Comment: Both all 'eyes' and 'cameras' are unchecked for the torusses, so they should be hidden in the viewport and renders.

Comment: Are viewport and render visibility the same for all of the modifiers?

Comment: Yes, the viewport and render visibility for all modifiers are the same. See the post, I updated it with a screenshot at the end.

Comment: Can you [provide](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file) the file to play with? Atm nothing indicates what could be wrong. Looks like the Boolean might work with viewport settings but fails for denser render geometry (subsurf at start of stack). And with Booleans failing you might get those results.

Comment: Please provide the .blend-file

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny & Gimli: I've added the .blend file, see the top of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by a small discrepancy between how the booleans are applied on a level 3 subdiv and a level 4 subdiv. Drop your render sub-div level down to 3 or move the torii so they create the correct behaviour with level 4 subdiv enabled in viewport.

[image: Viewport with level 4 subdiv]

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of looking at the subsurf differences for render and view. Do you have any idea what causes this issue with the boolean, and how to possibly fix it (except for lowering the subsurf)?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the boolean modifier, when using 4 subdivisions, the top torus 'cuts' the geometery instead of taking out the section it needs, which seems to be stuffing up the face normals making the second torus do what looks like a 'union' rather than a difference. 
https://ibb.co/mL96zJ

Comment: I have found making slight changes to the cutting object (torus) such as the thickness or position often fixes bugs like this. Unfortunately sometimes it doesn't just work as it should.